# Does gate::allows always return false within tests?

Tags: laravel

Inside `AuthServiceProvider` I have this gate:

```
  Gate::define('buy-seals', function ($user) {
        return true;
  });
```

If call the route `/test4` it returns 'YES', which imples that this Gate is setup correctly:

```
Route::get('/test4', function () {
    return Gate::allows('buy-seals') ? 'YES' : 'NI';
});
```

However, if I want to test the closure of the Gate in a PHPUnit test like this:

```
public function test_buy_seals_always_true() 
{
    $this->assertsTrue(Gate::allows('buy-seals'));
}
```

Then the test fails, meaning inside the test `Gate::allows('buy-seals')` is always false? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to specify `forUser($user)`

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
Gate::forUser($user)->allows('buy-seals');
```

Not sure why this necessary, but now it returns true in tests.

Comment: Gates return false by default for non-signed in users so you might also get it to work if you do `$this->actingAs($user)`